# Bootstrap - Unordered List Social Media Icons Formatting issues

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I built this website (http://ec2-54-186-23-70.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/index.html) on bootstrap; however, I'm having loading issues with the social media icons on the top right.

As you can see, when the website loads the social media icons stack on top of each other when they should be next to each other. However, when clicked on a link the formatting corrects itself and the social media icons are aligned next to each other.

This is the code:

```
                    <ul class="header-social"> 


                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/tinitroninc"><li class="facebook social-slide"></li></a>
                         <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/tinitroninc"><li class="youTube social-slide"></li></a>
                         <a href="https://twitter.com/TinitronInc"><li class="twitter social-slide"></li></a>
                         <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/tinitron-inc-?trk=company_name"><li class="linkedIn social-slide"></li></a>


                    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
 /* Social Media Header */
.header-social { 
    float:left; 
    margin-top:0px; 

}

.header-social ul {
        float:left; 
        padding:0; 
        margin-left:0px;
}

.header-social li {
    float:right; 
    list-style:none; 
    margin-left:5px;
}

.header-social span { 
    float:right; !important;
}

@media (mx-width: 767) {
.header-social {
        display:none;
}

.header-social ul {
        display:none;
}

.header-social li {
    display: none;
}


}

/* responsive Social Media Header */
@media (max-width: 992px) {
.header-social { 
    float:left;  !important;
    margin-left: -42px;
    margin-top:5px; 

}

.header-social ul {
        float:right; 
        padding:0; 
        margin-left:0px;
}

.header-social li {
        float:right; 
        list-style:none; 
        margin-left:5px;
    }

.header-social span { 
    float:right; 
    }
}
```

How can I correct this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Put your anchor links inside the list  elements.

```
<li><a>click me</a></li>
```

Comment: I'm loading the social media icons via CSS. If I change the <a href> to the inside of the <li> the link will not work. There is no anchor text with the link.

Any other suggestions? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wrap the anchor around an empty DIV that you actually sign the image to via CSS.